# Apache ProxyPass after PHP Script "authentication"

Tags: php, apache, authentication, proxy, frameworks

i hope you can help me with this:

I am using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse for getting access to a NAS website in my network.

Also i'm using a PHP Framework which is able to authenticate users against an LDAP server and uses an internal user role system.

Now to my question.

I'd like to use my framework to restrict the use of the ProxyPass, and to make it fit seamlessly into the design of the website i don't want to use the apache modules like http_auth or ldap_auth.

So the idea in steps is :

-open website
-authenticate via framework
-framework "allows" proxy reverse
-proxy loads

The recent situation is following:

.htaccess rewrites everything to index.php 
    (RewriteRule (.*) index.php)

And the Proxy is configured like this:

```
ProxyPass /nassystem http://10.0.0.1/
ProxyPassReverse /nassystem http://10.0.0.1/
```

With this configuration, the webserver directly proxies the request

```
http://server.local/nassystem
```

to the ip address, without even hesitating about any php script.

Do you have an idea or an advice how to deal with this situation?

Greetings,

Dwarfex

Comment: You should really be using auth at the server level, or be doing the proxy with php where you have access to all the app level stuff. You could set a cookie on authentication and use Apache to check for it's existence, but it won't be able to check it's validity, so it's by no means secure.

Comment: Yap i tought of the coockie but throw that thought away of as you say, the security reaseon. Is apache able to check for a PHP Session variable and it's content? 
I searched but didn't stumble on a fully working php proxy class.